# How can I create a new column and assign values to it based off of critieria?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
         lname    fname   rno_cd    eri_cd
    0    CRUISE   TOM     E         1
    1    DEPP     JOHNNY  Y         0
    2    DICAPR   LENARDO           1
    3    PITT     BRAD              1
    4    MOST     JEFF    A         0
    5    HANKS    TOM               1
    6    BRANDO   MARLON  C         1
    7    WILLIAMS ROBIN   F         1
    8    DOWNEY   ROBERT  B         1
    9    PACINO   AL      E         1
```

The codes in column ['rno_cd'] are defined as:

```
 A = AI/AK Native
 B = Asian
 C = Black/AA
 D = Hispanic
 E = White
 F = Asian
 G = Asian
 H = Haw/Pac Isl.
 Y = White
```

1)  I need to define these codes and place in a new column.
2)  I also need to somehow account for the blank values

The final result should look like:

```
         lname    fname   rno_cd    eri_cd  rno_defined
    0    CRUISE   TOM     E         1       White
    1    DEPP     JOHNNY  Y         0       White
    2    DICAPR   LENARDO           1       Unknown
    3    PITT     BRAD              1       Unknown   
    4    MOST     JEFF    A         0       AI/AK Native  
    5    HANKS    TOM               1       Unknown
    6    BRANDO   MARLON  C         1       Black/AA
    7    WILLIAMS ROBIN   F         1       Asian
    8    DOWNEY   ROBERT  B         1       Asian
    9    PACINO   AL      E         1       White
```

======================  MY CODING SO FAR ==================

I used the following but not sure if it is a solid solution.

```
In[1]: 
    df1['rno_cd'][df1.rno_cd.str.contains('A')] = 'AI/AK Native'
    df1['rno_cd'][df1.rno_cd.str.contains('B')] = 'Asian'
    df1['rno_cd'][df1.rno_cd.str.contains('C')] = 'Black/AA'
    df1['rno_cd'][df1.rno_cd.str.contains('D')] = 'Hispanic'
    df1['rno_cd'][df1.rno_cd.str.contains('E')] = 'White'
    df1['rno_cd'][df1.rno_cd.str.contains('F')] = 'Asian'
    df1['rno_cd'][df1.rno_cd.str.contains('G')] = 'Asian'
    df1['rno_cd'][df1.rno_cd.str.contains('H')] = 'HawPac'
    df1['rno_cd'][df1.rno_cd.str.contains('Y')] = 'White'


In[1]:  df1
Out[1]:  


         lname      fname      rno_cd   eri_cd
    0    SONJU      LAURIE     White     1
    1    FORTHOFER  KELLY      White     0
    2    PLILEY     JODY                 1
    3    NOEL       HEATHER              1
    4    MANNING    CYNTHIA    White     0
    5    NAUERTZ    ELIZABETH            1
    6    SCHMID     DAVID      White     1
    7    HINTHER    VICTORIA   White     1
    8    JOHNSON    B.         White     1
    9    MOORE      CAROL      White     1
    10   MARSHALL   JOY                  1
```

The limitation of this code is that it doesn't assign a value to the blank values from the original data set.  I also can't see the original code to verify the values are correct.

Any suggestions/comments/advise?

thanks.

Comment: Using both answers below from Taha and exp1orer helped me answer the question.  Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a dictionary, where the keys are the references, and values are names.

```
D={"A":"AI/AK Native","B":"Asian","C":"Black/AA","D":"Hispanic","E":"White","F":"Asian","G":"Asian","H":"Haw/Pac Isl","Y":"White"}
```

Then go through the `rno_cd` column, and apply a function that transform the data. You can use `apply` and function `tranform` where you can verify whether x is a key so you get the values using your dictionary `D[x]` if it's not the case, you just return `"unknown"`

```
data="""lname    fname   rno_cd    eri_cd
0    CRUISE   TOM     E         1
1    DEPP     JOHNNY  Y         0
2    DICAPR   LENARDO Nan       1
3    PITT     BRAD    Nan       1
4    MOST     JEFF    A         0
5    HANKS    TOM     Nan       1
6    BRANDO   MARLON  C         1
7    WILLIAMS ROBIN   F         1
8    DOWNEY   ROBERT  B         1
9    PACINO   AL      E         1"""

import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from io import StringIO

df= pd.read_csv(StringIO(data.decode('UTF-8')),delim_whitespace=True )


D={"A":"AI/AK Native","B":"Asian","C":"Black/AA","D":"Hispanic","E":"White","F":"Asian","G":"Asian","H":"Haw/Pac Isl","Y":"White"}

def transform(x):
    if x['rno_cd']=="Nan":
        return "Unknown"
    else:
        return D[x['rno_cd']]

df["rno_defined"]= df.apply(lambda x: transform(x) ,axis=1)

print df
```

Another way to do it:

```
df["rno_defined"]= map(lambda x: D[x] if x!="Nan" else "Unknown",df['rno_cd'].values)
```

Output:

```
      lname    fname rno_cd  eri_cd   rno_defined
0    CRUISE      TOM      E       1         White
1      DEPP   JOHNNY      Y       0         White
2    DICAPR  LENARDO    Nan       1       Unknown
3      PITT     BRAD    Nan       1       Unknown
4      MOST     JEFF      A       0  AI/AK Native
5     HANKS      TOM    Nan       1       Unknown
6    BRANDO   MARLON      C       1      Black/AA
7  WILLIAMS    ROBIN      F       1         Asian
8    DOWNEY   ROBERT      B       1         Asian
9    PACINO       AL      E       1         White
```

Answer (score 2):

Series (for example, columns of a DataFrame) have a convenient `map` method. You just need the encoding in a dictionary form:

```
 code_to_ethnicity: {'A': 'AI/AK Native',
                     'B': 'Asian'} #etc
df['rno_defined'] = df['rno_cd'].map(code_to_ethnicity)
```

When you describe 'blank values', I assume you mean empty strings: `''`. If you want to do something special for these, you can add it to the dictionary directly.

```
 code_to_ethnicity: {'A': 'AI/AK Native',
                     'B': 'Asian',
                     '': 'other}
```